# async validation function dont fire status changes and never became valid

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous

I have FormGroup  that includes controls.
I have async validation on specific control.
I subscribe for status changes event of the FormGroup,
But when the answer from async validation returned
the status changes doesnot fire  end still be 'PENDING'
i tried to do updateValueAndValidity but the errors removed and the status be Valid.

I tried a few things that didn't help:

1. take(1) and distinctUntilChanged() in the validation function
2. updateValueAndValidity() in the validation function
3. Call the server and set the control's errors manually

2.

```
control.valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(res => {
        let control = this.formService.getFormControlByName(component.name);
        let depentsControl = this.formService.getFormControlByName(component.dataDependency!.baseOnControlName);
        let params = {"controlValue": control?.value, "depentsValue": depentsControl?.value};
          this.dataService.getData(component.asyncCustomValidator!.className, component.asyncCustomValidator!.asyncFunctionName , params)
           .subscribe((data: any) =>{
            console.log('after async');
            if(data.isValid){
              control?.setErrors(null);
            }
            else{
              control?.setErrors({ asyncVal: data.errorMassage});
            }
            control?.updateValueAndValidity();
          });
        });
```

3.

```
  asyncValidator(validator: AsyncCustomValidator, baseOnControlName: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> =>{
      let depentsControl:any = null; 
      if(baseOnControlName){
        depentsControl = this.formService.getFormControlByName(baseOnControlName);
      }
      let params = {"controlValue": control.value, "depentsValue": depentsControl.value};
      return (this.dataService.getData(validator.className, validator.asyncFunctionName , params).pipe(map((data: any) =>{
        if(data.isValid){
          return null;
        }
        else{
          return { asyncVal: data.errorMassage};
        }
      }))).pipe(tap(() => this.formService.workflowFormGroup.updateValueAndValidity())); 
    }
  }
```